# Nftables configuration error: conflicting protocols specified: inet-service v. icmp

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, firewall, nftables

I am trying to build a **simple stateful firewall** with **nftables** following the [Arch Linux nftables guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nftables#Simple_stateful_firewall). I posted this question on the Arch Linux forum and never received an answer.

After completing the guide and rebooting my machine, **systemd** failed to load the **nftables.service**. To troubleshoot the error I ran:

```
systemctl status nftables
```

Here is the relevant output:

```
/etc/nftables.conf:7:17-25: Error: conflicting protocols specified: inet-service v. icmp
```

The error is complaining about a rule that I set for accepting new pings (icmp) in the input chain. Here is the rule and I don’t see anything wrong with it:

```
icmp type echo-request ct state new accept
```

If I remove the rule it will work. But I want the rule.

Here is my ruleset in **nftables.conf** after completing the guide:

```
    table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state established,related accept
        iif "lo" accept
        ct state invalid drop
        icmp type echo-request ct state new accept
        ip protocol udp ct state new jump UDP
        tcp flags & (fin | syn | rst | ack) == syn ct state new jump TCP
        ip protocol udp reject
        ip protocol tcp reject with tcp reset
        meta nfproto ipv4 counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject with icmp type prot-unreachable
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }

    chain TCP {
        tcp dport http accept
        tcp dport https accept
        tcp dport ssh accept
        tcp dport domain accept
    }

    chain UDP {
        tcp dport domain accept
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a syntax limitation of nftables 0.7 (or a few other versions): it didn't consider ICMP and ICMPv6 directly usable in the dual IPv4/IPv6 table `inet` without stating explicitly which IP protocol first:

So the rule:

```
icmp type echo-request ct state new accept
```

to work both on IPv4 and IPv6 has to be written twice like this:

**UPDATE**: actually one shouldn't rely for IPv6 on `nexthdr` pointing to the upper-layer protocol: there can be [Extension Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) between the Fixed Header and the upper-layer header (which comes last). Adding the correct syntax (using the meta-informations already providing protocol informations), and leaving my original answer striked, because I don't know if the "correct" syntax is valid with nftables 0.7:

```
meta nfproto ipv4 meta l4proto icmp icmp type echo-request ct state new accept
meta nfproto ipv6 meta l4proto icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request ct state new accept
```

```
ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request ct state new accept
ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request ct state new accept
```

giving the corresponding bytecode (displayed using `nft --debug=netlink list ruleset -a`):

```
inet filter input 9 8 
  [ meta load nfproto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000002 ]
  [ payload load 1b @ network header + 9 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ payload load 1b @ transport header + 0 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000008 ]
  [ ct load state => reg 1 ]
  [ bitwise reg 1 = (reg=1 & 0x00000008 ) ^ 0x00000000 ]
  [ cmp neq reg 1 0x00000000 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]

inet filter input 10 9 
  [ meta load nfproto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x0000000a ]
  [ payload load 1b @ network header + 6 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x0000003a ]
  [ payload load 1b @ transport header + 0 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000080 ]
  [ ct load state => reg 1 ]
  [ bitwise reg 1 = (reg=1 & 0x00000008 ) ^ 0x00000000 ]
  [ cmp neq reg 1 0x00000000 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]
```

ICMP is IP protocol 1, echo-request value 8.
ICMPv6 is IPv6 protocol 58 (0x3a), its echo-request value 128 (0x80).

Newer nftables 0.9 accepts directly the rule `icmp type echo-request ct state new accept`, but its corresponding bytecode is then only:

```
inet filter input 9 8 
  [ meta load nfproto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000002 ]
  [ meta load l4proto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000001 ]
  [ payload load 1b @ transport header + 0 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000008 ]
  [ ct load state => reg 1 ]
  [ bitwise reg 1 = (reg=1 & 0x00000008 ) ^ 0x00000000 ]
  [ cmp neq reg 1 0x00000000 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]
```

meaning it's dealing only with ICMP, not also ICMPv6, which should still be added with an additional rule, simply as:

```
icmpv6 type echo-request ct state new accept
```

giving back the equivalent bytecode of former version:

```
inet filter input 10 9 
  [ meta load nfproto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x0000000a ]
  [ meta load l4proto => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x0000003a ]
  [ payload load 1b @ transport header + 0 => reg 1 ]
  [ cmp eq reg 1 0x00000080 ]
  [ ct load state => reg 1 ]
  [ bitwise reg 1 = (reg=1 & 0x00000008 ) ^ 0x00000000 ]
  [ cmp neq reg 1 0x00000000 ]
  [ immediate reg 0 accept ]
```